# Cannot run a large structure filled with arrays win C

Tags: c, assembly, arduino, stm32, can-bus

I'm building a [SAE J1939](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Open-SAE-J1939) library for embedded systems such as Arduino, STM32, AVR etc.

But I have an issue I don't understand. First when I compile. No error!
But when I run, I get this assembler error. It's all about the `J1939` struct.

Why does this happen? Is the heap to small?

> Can't find a source file at
> "C:\mingw810\i686-810-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\build\gcc-8.1.0\i686-w64-mingw32\libgcc/../../../../../src/gcc-8.1.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S"
> Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its
> location.

[image]

Run this code below to reproduce the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdint.h"

/* PGN: 0x00E800 - Storing the Acknowledgement from the reading process */
struct Acknowledgement {
    uint8_t control_byte;                           /* This indicates the status of the requested information about PGN: */
    uint8_t group_function_value;                   /* The function code that specify cause of the control byte e.g time out or aborted */
    uint8_t address;                                /* Address from the ECU where the acknowledgement is comming from */
    uint32_t PGN_of_requested_info;                 /* Information request about the PGN */
};

/* PGN: 0x00EC00 - Storing the Transport Protocol Connection Management from the reading process */
struct TP_CM {
    uint8_t control_byte;                           /* What type of message are we going to send */
    uint16_t total_message_size;                    /* Total bytes our complete message includes */
    uint8_t number_of_packages;                     /* How many times we are going to send packages via TP_DT */
    uint32_t PGN_of_the_packeted_message;           /* Our message is going to activate a PGN */
};

/* PGN: 0x00EB00 - Storing the Transport Protocol Data Transfer from the reading process */
struct TP_DT {
    uint8_t sequence_number;                        /* When this sequence number is the same as number_of_packages from TP_CM, then we have our complete message */
    uint8_t data[7][256];                           /* Package data of 2D array where first index is data0 -> data6 and second index is sequence of the data */
};

/* PGN: 0x00EE00 - Storing the Address claimed from the reading process */
struct Name {
    uint32_t identity_number;                       /* Specify the ECU serial ID - 0 to 2097151 */
    uint16_t manufacturer_code;                     /* Specify the ECU manufacturer code - 0 to 2047 */
    uint8_t function_instance;                      /* Specify the ECU function number - 0 to 31 */
    uint8_t ECU_instance;                           /* Specify the ECU number - 0 to 7 */
    uint8_t function;                               /* Specify the ECU function - 0 to 255 */
    uint8_t vehicle_system;                         /* Specify the type of vehicle where ECU is located - 0 to 127 */
    uint8_t arbitrary_address_capable;              /* Specify if the ECU have right to change address if addresses conflicts - 0 to 1 */
    uint8_t industry_group;                         /* Specify the group where this ECU is located - 0 to 7 */
    uint8_t vehicle_system_instance;                /* Specify the vehicle system number - 0 to 15 */
};

/* PGN: 0x00FECA - Storing the DM1 Active diagnostic trouble codes from the reading process */
struct DM1 {
    /* These are SAE lamps can have 1 = ON and 0 = OFF */
    uint8_t SAE_lamp_status_malfunction_indicator;
    uint8_t SAE_lamp_status_red_stop;
    uint8_t SAE_lamp_status_amber_warning;
    uint8_t SAE_lamp_status_protect_lamp;
    uint8_t SAE_flash_lamp_malfunction_indicator;
    uint8_t SAE_flash_lamp_red_stop;
    uint8_t SAE_flash_lamp_amber_warning;
    uint8_t SAE_flash_lamp_protect_lamp;

    /* Fault location, problem and codes */
    uint32_t SPN;                                   /* Location where the fault exist */
    uint8_t FMI;                                    /* Type of problem */
    uint8_t SPN_conversion_method;                  /* If SPN_conversion_method = 1 that means Diagnostics Trouble Code are aligned using a newer conversion method. If SPN_conversion_method = 0 means one of the three Diagnostics Trouble Code conversion methods is used and ECU manufacture shall know which of the three methods is used */
    uint8_t occurence_count;                        /* This tells how many times failure has occurred. Every time fault goes from inactive to active, the occurence_count is incremented by 1. If fault becomes active for more than 126 times the occurence_count remains 126 */
};

/* PGN: 0x00D800 - Storing the DM15 response from the reading process */
struct DM15 {
    uint16_t number_of_allowed_bytes;               /* How many bytes we are allowed to write or read to */
    uint8_t status;                                 /* Status of the response */
    uint32_t EDC_parameter;                         /* Status code */
    uint8_t EDCP_extention;                         /* Describe how we should interpret the EDC parameter as a status code or error code */
    uint16_t seed;                                  /* Response of the key if we need more key or no key at all */
};

/* PGN: 0x00D700 - Storing the DM16 binary data transfer from the reading process */
struct DM16 {
    uint8_t number_of_occurences;                   /* How many bytes we have sent */
    uint8_t raw_binary_data[256];                   /* Here we store the bytes */
};

/* Storing the error codes from the reading process */
struct DM {
    uint8_t errors_dm1_active;                      /* How many errors of DM1 we have right now */
    uint8_t errors_dm2_active;                      /* How many errors of DM2 is active */
    struct DM1 dm1[256];                            /* dm1 can contains multiple error messages */
    struct DM1 dm2[256];                            /* dm2 contains previously active errors from dm1 */
    struct DM15 dm15;                               /* dm15 is the memory access response from DM14 memory request */
    struct DM16 dm16;                               /* dm16 is the binary data transfer after DM15 memory response (if it was proceeded) */
    /* Add more DM here */
};

/* PGN: 0x00FEDA - Storing the software identification from the reading process */
struct Software_identification {
    uint8_t length_of_each_identification;          /* The length of each identification - Not part of J1939 standard */
    uint8_t number_of_fields;                       /* How many numbers contains in the identifications array */
    uint8_t identifications[256];                   /* This can be for example ASCII */
};

/* PGN: 0x00FDC5 - Storing the ECU identification from the reading process */
struct ECU_identification {
    uint8_t length_of_each_field;                   /* The real length of the fields - Not part of J1939 standard */
    uint8_t ecu_part_number[256];                   /* ASCII field */
    uint8_t ecu_serial_number[256];                 /* ASCII field */
    uint8_t ecu_location[256];                      /* ASCII field */
    uint8_t ecu_type[256];                          /* ASCII field */
    uint8_t ecu_manufacturer[256];                  /* ASCII field */
    uint8_t ecu_hardware_version[256];              /* ASCII field */
};

/* PGN: 0x00FEEB - Storing the component identification from the reading process */
struct Component_identification {
    uint8_t length_of_each_field;                   /* The real length of the fields - Not part of J1939 standard */
    uint8_t component_product_date[256];            /* ASCII field */
    uint8_t component_model_name[256];              /* ASCII field */
    uint8_t component_serial_number[256];           /* ASCII field */
    uint8_t component_unit_name[256];               /* ASCII field */
};

/* PGN: 0x00FE30 (65072) to 0x00FE3F (65087) */
struct Auxiliary_valve_command {
    uint8_t standard_flow;                          /* Command flow */
    uint8_t fail_safe_mode;                         /* If the user want the valve to go to neutral */
    uint8_t valve_state;                            /* Retract, Extend, Neutral, Init, Error etc */
};

/* PGN: 0x00FE10 (65040) to 0x00FE1F (65055) */
struct Auxiliary_valve_estimated_flow {
    uint8_t extend_estimated_flow_standard;         /* A measurement */
    uint8_t retract_estimated_flow_standard;        /* A measurement */
    uint8_t valve_state;                            /* Retract, Extend, Neutral, Init, Error etc */
    uint8_t fail_safe_mode;                         /* The mode if we are going to use fail safe mode or not */
    uint8_t limit;                                  /* Enter a limit code */
};

/* PGN: 0x00C400 (50176) */
struct General_purpose_valve_command {
    uint8_t standard_flow;                          /* Command flow */
    uint8_t fail_safe_mode;                         /* If the user want the valve to go to neutral */
    uint8_t valve_state;                            /* Retract, Extend, Neutral, Init, Error etc */
    uint16_t extended_flow;                         /* Another command flow */
};

/* PGN: 0x00C600 (50688) */
struct General_purpose_valve_estimated_flow {
    uint8_t extend_estimated_flow_standard;         /* A measurement */
    uint8_t retract_estimated_flow_standard;        /* A measurement */
    uint8_t valve_state;                            /* Retract, Extend, Neutral, Init, Error etc */
    uint8_t fail_safe_mode;                         /* The mode if we are going to use fail safe mode or not */
    uint8_t limit;                                  /* Enter a limit code */
    uint16_t extend_estimated_flow_extended;        /* A measurement */
    uint16_t retract_estimated_flow_extended;       /* A measurement */
};

struct Auxiliary_valve_measured_position {
    uint16_t measured_position_procent;             /* Procent position */
    uint8_t valve_state;                            /* Retract, Extend, Neutral, Init, Error etc */
    uint16_t measured_position_micrometer;          /* Micrometer position */
};

typedef struct {
    /* For information about other ECU */
    uint8_t number_of_ECU;
    uint8_t number_of_cannot_claim_address;
    uint8_t ECU_address[256];
    struct Acknowledgement acknowledgement[256];
    struct TP_CM tp_cm[256];
    struct TP_DT tp_dt[256];
    struct Name name[256];
    struct DM dm[256];
    struct Software_identification software_identification[256];
    struct ECU_identification ecu_identification[256];
    struct Component_identification component_identification[256];
    struct Auxiliary_valve_estimated_flow auxiliary_valve_estimated_flow[256][16];
    struct General_purpose_valve_estimated_flow general_purpose_valve_estimated_flow[256];
    struct Auxiliary_valve_measured_position auxiliary_valve_measured_position[256][16];

    /* For information about this ECU */
    struct Name this_name;
    uint8_t this_ECU_address;
    struct DM this_dm;
    struct Software_identification this_software_identification;
    struct ECU_identification this_ecu_identification;
    struct Component_identification this_component_identification;
    struct Auxiliary_valve_command this_auxiliary_valve_command[16];
    struct General_purpose_valve_command this_general_purpose_valve_command;


} J1939;

int main(void) {

    J1939 j1939;
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Is the error you show the *complete* output when you build? It also seems like you're trying to build with an (incomplete) installation of GCC targeted not for your platform but for the system host using Cygwin.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is no error at all. It runs with the exit code `-1 073 741 571`. Nothing happen. I have installed MinGW on Windows 10.

Comment: Do you get the error when you try to debug your code (from the debugger)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No. Only the message above

Comment: As I thought, the error comes from the debugger because you're in some code that doesn't really belong to your program. Step up the call-stack to the `main` function and the code will be availab.e That message is unrelated to the actual cause of the problem you have.

Comment: It's the stack not the heap that the variable is allocated in. You probably are overflowing it with that large variable. Do you know what the size is? May want to try allocating on the heap instead (with `malloc`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I delete `J1939 j1939;` statement, then I get no errors. How can I set up the call-stack to the main?

Comment: @kaylum You think my arrays are to large?

Comment: As a possible hint, instead of creating a `J1939` variable, print its size (`printf("J1939 size = %zu\n", sizeof(J1939));`) What is the size of the structure?

Comment: Can't tell exactly just by inspection but it looks large. You have the code. Print its size. Then tell us what it is.

Comment: And remember that local variables usually are put on the stack, which is a limited resource. On Windows the default stack per process is a single MiB. Which is still *much* larger than the stack (and often the total memory) of the embedded systems you really want to target.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `J1939 size = 3417192`

Comment: Hmm...If I comment `struct DM dm[256];`, then the statement `J1939 j1939;` will work.

Comment: So over 3 MiB? That's *way* to large! Your target platforms total memory counts in the tens to hundreds (if you're lucky) KiB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I guess I need to have smaller arrays then? Or is it another way to do?

Comment: Off-topic: sub-optimal aligned, these structures.

Comment: This is the typical Eclipse file path bugs. Easiest fix is to get rid of Eclipse and use literally any other IDE ever made instead. Though why are you trying to compile this for Windows instead of for the embedded target?

Comment: @Lundin I fixed it by reducing the size of the struct. Not it's only 6.5 kB instead of 3 Mb.

Comment: Why would the size of variables have anything to do with "Can't find a source file" file path errors? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin Perhaps the C compiler is crap? Low quality? I'm using MinGW. I have another weird thing also to show. Do you have Eclipse and a C compiler?

Comment: @Lundin Variabel storlek på denna array klarar inte debuggern utav. Jag får error. Men kör jag bara utan debugger, så fungerar det. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Open-SAE-J1939/blob/c0d918bb219205c7b0c38ae0b0ed0ba9bfef25bc/Src/SAE%20J1939-21%20Transport%20Layer/SAE_J1939_Transport_Protocol_Data_Transfer.c#L28

Comment: English please. This is very likely an IDE issue, like I said from the start. Yes I've used plenty of Eclipse versions. It is by far the worst IDE ever made by mankind.

Comment: @Lundin Really...worst? I think Eclipse is the perfect and best IDE ever. Works like a charm in Ubuntu. Can't find any multi-language IDE. I tried to use VSCode, but i did not like it. Felt cheap.

Comment: @MrYui "It is great! Except it doesn't work...". It is buggy, slow and broken in general. And has been for a decade by now, nothing ever gets fixed, just new bugs getting added. I'd much rather code in notepad.exe, Turbo C or some obscure Unix editor. I have used some 50+ different IDEs in the past 20 years, Eclipse is the worst by far.

Comment: @Lundin Never heard that Eclipse is the worst IDE ever made. I thought Eclipse was a real enterprise stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235112/discussion-between-lundin-and-mryui).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is not a compilation error. You execute a debugger and try to debug a part of program without located sources. This could happen if your program stops in a compiled library. Then we can use a assembler instruction only. As mentioned above try to set breakpoint into your main() funcion.